# iOS In App Purchase-nothing happens

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I had a customer how contacted me since my app was just what he needed, and the In App Purchase did not work. After seeing the price and all, when he pressed the "Purchase" button, nothing happened. No app crash, just nothing. Just waiting with no response.

We had a dialogue and he tried many things: deleted the app, downloaded a fresh copy, reset his phone, but the purchase did not go through. He has no restrictions activated.

So I became curious. How many potential customers experience this problem?

Since I went from the Paid model over to the try-before-buy and the In App Purchase, my sales has reduced dramatically. I was disappointed: "do they not like my app after they have tried it?"

After my customer contacted me, and I could not find any bugs in my code, I uploaded a "debug-version" which logs the following info to a web server/database:
- the time and date when the purchase button is pressed.
- the time and date when payment is successful and contents is provided.
along with a generated UUID key.

Today is the first day with the debug version (which logs into a simple web app I made for the purpose), and 50 % of all tries have failed: they have no time and date for successful payment, after the purchase button was pressed.

Here are the lines of code being called after the "Purchase" button has been pressed:

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:proUpgradeProduct];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

Has anybody experienced the same?
Any suggestion about how to move forward?

Comment: I don't know what the issue is, but I presume you have extensively testing in-app purchases using the sandbox environment?

Comment: Of course I have tested in the sandbox. (But obviously not enough, since I am sure the fault is not With Apple). I have tried to reproduce both in the sandbox and with the production, but with no luck. And half of who tries, are successful. If all failed, it would be easier, then I could trace it myself...

Comment: I replaced my whole In App Purchase implementation with MKStoreKit (https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit).

Comment: I replaced my whole In App Purchase implementation with [MKStoreKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit). But I get the same behaviour. Now, 12 hours after it was approved by the App Store, I have logged 3 attempts, with 3 failures. I have tested it on my devices with both test users and production users without beeing able to reproduce. I have one end user who I know has the problem: how could he help me providing info about what is happening under the hood? Logs are impossible to obtain without XCODE?